# Problem with authorization code in google collab

Tags: python

I want to mount my drive to my collab notebook. I ran the following code.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

After I paste my authentication code and press enter, nothing happens.
The cell is still running, though

How shall I proceed?

Comment: Issue Solved: Update your firefox browser or just switch to chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced this problem an hour ago. Don't know if it is still actual for you, but updating firefox from 65 to 69 helped me.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I just switched to chrome and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related to the authorization itself; the authorization copy button was not working, so instead of clicking it, select the code and copy it directly.

[image]